# Pause CFTimeInterval Timer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

In my game I have a timer in my update loop that updates a label based upon the interval returned in this line:

```
elapsedTime = 90 - (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);
```

Now 90 is the time we tick down from. I set startTime like so:

```
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

Now what I am aiming to do is "pause" this timer when I go to my pause menu. However I just cannot wrap my head around the logistics of it.

When I pause should I set startTime to 0? If so, what would I do during the resume method?

Basically if the user pauses the game with 85 seconds to go, I want the user to come back from the pause screen with 85 seconds to go still. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer. I just did what I was doing now but I included another timer for the paused screen and I just add it up continually when paused and then I incorporate that timer into my game timer and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the amount of time, that passed since the timer started.

With NSDate you can store the startTime of the timer and than use -timeIntervalSinceNow to retrieve the time that passed.